# NullPointerException on start up when using Hibernate 4 with Grails 3.2.4

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, groovy, grails-orm

I followed the instructions in the [Grails 3.2 documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html#_hibernate_4_usage) to switch from hibernate 5 (the default) to hibernate 4. However, now my application won't start. I get the exception shown below on start up.

```
01/12/2017 11:52:55 PST ERROR main SpringApplication:839 - Application startup failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1337)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl$15.run(MetaClassImpl.java:3290)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.addProperties(MetaClassImpl.java:3288)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3265)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.<init>(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:38)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createClassMetaClassGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:373)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.createGetPropertySite(AbstractCallSite.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.acceptGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:296)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.configureLiquibase(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:96)
    at org.grails.plugins.databasemigration.DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.doWithSpring(DatabaseMigrationGrailsPlugin.groovy:55)
    at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:555)
    at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:167)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
```

Some quick googling seems to imply that this error is caused by some mismatch in the dependencies for the project. However, the Grails 3.2 docs only mention adding the hibernate 4 dependencies, but not changing any of the other ones. Does anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First refresh dependencies using -

```
grails clean --refresh-dependencies
```

Build a dependency report using this command -

```
grails dependency-report
```

Confirm that application is using hibernate 4 dependency. Find out if hibernate 5 dependency is being used from any of its plugins. If so exclude it in your build.gradle file from the respective plugin.

Comment: Then try `grails run-app`

Comment: That did the trick. Turns out I was using a version of the database migration plugin that was depending on hibernate 5 and pulling in the dependency that mismatched with my use of hibernate 4. I downgraded to version 2.0.0 of the database migration plugin that works with Grails 3 and hibernate 4 (according to the docs here: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration), and that did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.